# how to insert get_element_count in python code

Tags: python, robotframework

I have to convert following robot framework keyword in to python code. Can you please help me out.

Robot framework sample keyword:

```
*variables*
${locator} xpath=(//div[@it="testID"])[2]

*keyword*
sample keyword  ${count}  Get Element Count ${locator}
```

In python file. I used the following command

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def _helper keyword(locator):
    count=BuiltIn.run_keyword(get_element_count,locator)
```

When I executed it, I received the following error message: `NameError: name 'get_element_count' is not defined.`

Answer (score 2):

First, no need the `xpath=` in your xpath, simply use:

```
*variables*
${locator} | (//div[@it="testID"])[2]
```

Secondly, get_element_count is a keyword come from SeleniumLibrary, not Builtin. Therefore, you need to import SeleniumLibrary to call it:

```
def get_element_count(locator):
    context = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
    return   context.get_element_count(locator)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `get_element_count` is actually from the SeleniumLibrary; for its call to fail like this, it probably means you don't have it imported in the context you're running your function (e.g. the suite this function is called doesn't have `Library    SeleniumLibrary` in it, or in any of the resources it imports).

Once you resolve that, there's a slightly better way to call its methods - instead of going through `run_keyword`, you can use [`get_library_instance()`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance) and directly call its keywords:

```
se_lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
cnt = se_lib.get_element_count(locator)
```

For this to work though, the library obviously needs to be imported - to have an instance to get.

---

*P.S. Don't use "count" for a variable name - it's a python's builtin function you've just overridden - hidden bugs downstream ;)*